# Question: libraries dependency Spark Scala in Intellij --Unresolved dependencies path: resolved

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependencies, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Checking the logs is usually helpful. When you use:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.2"
```

you will find a repo link:

```
not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.13/3.1.2/spark-core_2.13-3.1.2.pom
```

Here you can see that you can't reach the exact dir because of `%%` always tries to find itself but can't reach.
Use `%` only and try to give the manual path like this added the postfix to spark_sql.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.12" % "3.1.2" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "3.1.2" % "provided"
```

Comment: Hi JxD and welcome to StackOverflow! Have you read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?? Try to remove your answer in the question please :)

Answer (score 1):

According to JxD’s own response:

> Here, you can see that you can't reach the exact dir because of `%%`.
> Use `%` only and try to give the manual path like this added as the postfix to spark_sql dependency.
>
> `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.12" % "3.1.2" % "provided"`
>
> `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "3.1.2" % "provided"`